# in Cesium, Why the request of 'Cesium/Workers/TerrainEncoding.js' is accidental?

Tags: webgl, mapbox-gl-js, cesiumjs

```
const map = new Cesium.Viewer('map-3d', {
        homeButton: false, // 关闭主页视角按钮
        animation: false, // 关闭左下角动画组件
        baseLayerPicker: true, // 关闭底图图层切换组件
        geocoder: false, // 关闭搜索定位
        timeline: false, // 关闭时间线部件
        navigationHelpButton: false, // 关闭右上角导航帮助按钮
        navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false, // 不显示提示
        infoBox: false,
        selectionIndicator: false,
        sceneModePicker: false, // 关闭二三维切换
        scene3DOnly: true, // 只渲染 3D，节省资源
        skyBox: false, // 关闭天空
        skyAtmosphere: false, // 关闭大气
        fullscreenElement: document.getElementById('map-container'), // * 要全屏的元素
    })
const terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
    url: 'xxxx',
})
map.terrainProvider = terrainProvider
```

the problem details:

because of the request of Cesium/Workers/TerrainEncoding.js is accidental, result in my globe is the pure black globe and can not use normally.

please tell me the possible reason that cause it.

Comment: Try setting `window.CESIUM_BASE_URL`

Comment: it have been setting previously, such as window.CESIUM_BASE_URL = 'xxxx/static/web-libs/cesiumjs/1.70.1/Cesium/', 'window.CESIUM_BASE_URL = './vendors/libs/Cesium/''